# iterate group in array reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am bringing data in a reactive form. I want to iterate a group within an array according to the data I have.

This is what my data structure looks like:

```
{
  nombre: 'Inca Suprema'
  precios: [
    {
      precio: 16,
      variante: 'Personal'
    },
    {
      precio: 28,
      variante: 'Mediana'
    },
    {
      precio: 38,
      variante: 'Familiar'
    },
  
  ]
}
```

What I need to achieve is that the array is loaded like this:

[image]

How can I achieve it? I have tried this, but I get `null` as a result. With `this.data.item.precios` I get the array `precios`

component.ts

```
 this.formItem.addControl('precios', this.fb.array([
        this.data.item.precios.forEach(element => {
          this.fb.group({
            variante: [element.variante],
            precio: [element.precio],
          });
        })
      ]));
```

component.html

```
<div formArrayName="precios" class="col-12">
            <div *ngFor="let precio of formItem.controls['precios']['controls']; let i = index;">
              <div [formGroupName]="i" class="d-flex">
                <div class="row gx-3">
                  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="col-6">
                    <mat-label>Variante</mat-label>
                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="variante">
                  </mat-form-field>
                  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="col-6">
                    <mat-label>Precio</mat-label>
                    <span matPrefix>S/. &nbsp;</span>
                    <input matInput type="number" formControlName="precio">
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <div class="pt-1">
                  <button class="ms-2" matSuffix mat-icon-button (click)="eliminarPrecio(i)" [disabled]="i === 0">
                    <i-tabler name="trash"></i-tabler>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: I think you need to replace the forEach by a map when you want to add the precios control. forEach doesn't return the array of new formGroups hence your formArray is not populated, using map instead will return a value

Answer (score 0):

The forEach method does not return a table, replace it by a map method instead

```
this.formItem.addControl('precios', this.fb.array(
  this.data.map(element =>
     this.fb.group({
        variante: [element.variante],
        precio: [element.precio]
     })
  )
))
```